# What is a composite URI?

Tags: url

I have read the term "composite URI", but I'm not familiar with what it means. Is there such a thing?

I have a CompositeUri class in an application I'm building and I would like to know if I should choose a different name.

Comment: I seem to have asked a semi-decidable question. If there is a technical meaning to the term I can get a definite answer, but if there isn't we may never know... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [ShrinkWrap](https://code.google.com/p/shrinkwrap/), a composite URI is one that refers to an aggregate of multiple CSS or javascript files e.g.

`http://example.com/css/hello.css+world.css`

That composite URI denotes the contents of `http://example.com/css/world.css` appended to the contents of `http://example.com/css/hello.css`.

Answer (score 1):

Composite generally means something made up on a few things. For example, composite keys in databases are made up from multiple fields, which together guarentee uniqueness.
A composite URL could be anything that fits that description, but would maybe be like the SO urls which include what your viewing (question), it's ID and some friendlier string.

Comment: Yes, that's the sense I'm using it in for my project. I was just wondering if there was another technical meaning I had not considered.